# Having some problems in using the site

Tags: support

First of all, I don't have this problem all the time.

It started only from yesterday when I decided to bring out an old laptop that was last used around 2012. After that it was not used until yesterday.

I tried to browse Hinduism.SE on it and found out that I was having problems. Only link that was click-able for me was the "profile". The activity and several others were not clickable.

And, I was also not able to ask any questions etc.

I thought it might have something to do with the browser I was using (Goggle Chrome), so I switched to Firefox. And, it signaled what the real problem is.

It says the site requires some Javascript to load but which did not for some reasons.

See the screenshot:

[image]

So, what shall I do now to solve the problem? I checked that the Java was up to date in the laptop.

Comment: On Firefox, write `about:config` in address bar and press enter; search for javascript and check to ensure whether `javascript.enabled` is set to true or not.

Comment: Just to let you know, JavaScript is different from Java.

Comment: See [What's this: “Stack Overflow requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load.”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260115) and [Use of ajax.googleapis.com not China friendly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258288)

Comment: In short, it could be due to some missing javascript library. Post error from Chrome console. Press F12 while on Chrome and see error message under "console" tab.

Comment: @Pandya Ok i have checked tht.. tht is set as true.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Did like u said.. but under "console" there isn't anything

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Yes i hv mistakenly wrote java in place of javascript.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Now the problem seems solved at least on Chrome.

Comment: @Rickross Ok. If you have still problems, you can update chrome and check again. As of now, latest version of chrome is  66.0.3359.181 .

Comment: The browser might not be updated. Please check your browser is in the list. [Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161/357396) Also  [“Stack Overflow requires external JavaScript from another domain” message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89433/357396)